# how to get random questions picked by machine in C

Tags: c

i am making a program in C where i ask the user 10 questions and i have a list of 20 questions. I want the machine to randomly pick and ask any 10 questions. Can anyone help me how to do that?

Comment: Post your efforts so far

Comment: Shuffle the array randomly, then use the first 10 questions in the array.

Comment: StackOverflow is *not* a do-my-homework site. You may want to use some [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). Look into some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site. Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). For your next question here, give some [MCVE]

Comment: Generate random numbers. Use `% 20` to index into the array. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822323/how-to-generate-a-random-int-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Randomizing questions on a quiz and calculating percentage correct in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527960/randomizing-questions-on-a-quiz-and-calculating-percentage-correct-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

As an outline:

```
    struct Q {
        char *q;
        int hasbeenselected;
    } q[20];
    int n;
    //
    // fill q with your questions and set hasbeenselected to 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        do {
            n= rand()%20;
        } while (q[n].hasbeenselected==1);
        // now ask question q[n].q
        q[n].hasbeenselected= 1;
    }
```